# Using a share and random function with a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, random, share, viewflipper

My app has a few view flippers with 20-40 text strings in each. I have a previous and next buttons to cycle through the text strings. Is it possible to add a random and share button that will give you a random text string from the viewflipper the user is using. And if the user likes the specific textstring they are viewing, can that be shared with the ACTION_SEND method to Facebook, Twitter, etc?

I cannot find examples of a random or share from within a TextFlipper! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly set a listener to your viewFlipper, but pushing that to facebook is a bit more complicated than a ACTION_SEND... you have to authenticate your app via an oAuth process to give your app permission to push to those social networks. Also, I imagine you can set a random number generator and open that index of the viewFlipper... pseudo code:

```
 RandomNumber myRandom = new RandomNumber();
 myRandom = myRandom % viewFlipper.size();
 show viewFlipper[myRandom];
```

*clearly this code wont work, merely pseudocode*

Comment: Does the myRandom = myRandom % viewFlipper.size(); give you a value within the range of the number of children within the ViewFlipper parent?

Comment: well, hypothetically yes. % is a modulo operation. Basically, it produces a value between 0 and the given operand. an example: 98 % 10 = 8 ... (98 / 10) = 9 remainder 8. then modulo operation gives you said remainder.